# How is "parking" split (hyphenated) at the end of the line?

Tags: spelling, hyphens

How should be the word `parking` correctly split at the end of the line? Should it be `par-` `king` or `park-` `ing`? The latter is suggested by my word processor, but I would say the former is correct. Which one is it?

Comment: We generally hyphenate at morpheme boundaries, so the separated pieces are more intelligible - for instance, *park* is a free morpheme (word) and *-ing* is a bound morpheme or suffix. This is not the same point at which syllable boundaries fall in speech.

Comment: For future reference, [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/parking) shows both hy·phen·a·tion boundaries and [si-lab-ik] breaks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typesetting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The former is how we divide *parking* into syllables in speech (following the Maximum Onset Principle):

> /ˈpɑr·kɪŋ/

The latter is how we divide *parking* when we need to break it across lines in writing.  We identify the suffix *-ing* and separate it from the previous morpheme, ignoring pronunciation:

> park·ing

However, there is an exception to this rule.  If a letter before the suffix has been doubled, the hyphen goes between the doubled pair:

> plan·**n**ing　　　　*(not *plan**n**·ing)*

Comment: Oh, so both are in fact correct? Amazing.

Comment: @theswine no, only `park-ing` is correct.

Comment: One is acceptable for speech, the other is correct for writing. If I want to _pronounce_ it as "park-ing", it's correct, but sounds odd. A similar case: "mistake". It is often pronounced "mi-stake", but should be written "mis-take", as its origin is a wrong/erroneous (_mis_) action (_take_).